# How to remove a QVBoxLayout from a QWidget or convert it to a QGridLayout?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I am trying to do some modifications to a GUI. My GUI is built on a QWidget. Initially I had just a QPushButton in the QWidget which then got deleted and was replaced by a QGridlayout housing a bunch of other stuff. Now I want to initially have two buttons held in a QVBoxLayout which get deleted and the QVBoxLayout gets deleted and/or replaced with the QGridLayout which then houses the next items.

The problem: I can't delete and/or replace the QVBosLayout with the QGridLayout.

Minimal reproducible example below. You need PyQt5 to run

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_Form():

    def __init__(self):
        self.nCode_analysis_set_up = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.nCode_analysis_set_up.resize(300, 100)
        self.nCode_analysis_set_up.setWindowFlags(self.nCode_analysis_set_up.windowFlags() | QtCore.Qt.MSWindowsFixedSizeDialogHint)
        self.nCode_analysis_set_up.setWindowTitle("nCode analysis set-up")
        self.Box = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.nCode_analysis_set_up)
        self.importButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.nCode_analysis_set_up)
        self.importButton.setText("Open import model")
        self.importButton.clicked.connect(self.input_model)
        self.Box.addWidget(self.importButton)

    def input_model(self):
        self.importButton.deleteLater()
        self.Box.deleteLater()
        self.Box = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.nCode_analysis_set_up)
        self.analysis_type_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.nCode_analysis_set_up)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ui = Ui_Form()
    ui.nCode_analysis_set_up.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not delete widgets since it usually brings more problems than benefits, instead use a QStackWidget or QStackedLayout:

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_Form:
    def __init__(self):
        self.nCode_analysis_set_up = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.nCode_analysis_set_up.resize(300, 100)
        self.nCode_analysis_set_up.setWindowFlags(
            self.nCode_analysis_set_up.windowFlags()
            | QtCore.Qt.MSWindowsFixedSizeDialogHint
        )
        self.nCode_analysis_set_up.setWindowTitle("nCode analysis set-up")

        self.stacked = QtWidgets.QStackedLayout(self.nCode_analysis_set_up)

        widget1 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        box_1 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(widget1)
        self.importButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton()
        self.importButton.setText("Open import model")
        self.importButton.clicked.connect(self.input_model)
        box_1.addWidget(self.importButton)

        widget2 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        box_2 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(widget2)
        self.analysis_type_label = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.analysis_type_label.setText("Label")
        box_2.addWidget(self.analysis_type_label)

        self.stacked.addWidget(widget1)
        self.stacked.addWidget(widget2)

    def input_model(self):
        self.stacked.setCurrentIndex(1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ui = Ui_Form()
    ui.nCode_analysis_set_up.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```